# Jquery drag/drop copies cell content instead of moving it

Tags: jquery, cell, draggable, droppable

I have 2 tables:

- Table 1 holds static data which can be copied to any location within table 2.
- Table 2 can be updated by the data copied from table 1 OR by **moving** data around in this table.

Everything works, except for the **moving**. It **copies** the content when I drag/drop.

Anybody got a clue?

Here you can have a look at the [online sample](http://www.num1.nl/dragdrop/index.php):

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a work around. I now simply remove the content from the original TD. And I added an extra table to serve as a trash bin.

The online sample does everything it should do. However, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it. I am rather inexperienced if it comes to jquery.

So if anybody has a more elegant solution that does the same thing, I am very willing to learn :)

Just in case, here is the JQ-code I use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var td1 = $("#table1 td");
var td2 = $("#table2 td");
var bin = $("#trash td");

td1.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: "0.5",
    revert: "invalid"
});

td2.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: "0.5",
    revert: "invalid"
});

td2.droppable({
    accept: 'td',
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // check from which table we are dragging
        var fromTable = $(ui.draggable).closest("table").attr("id");
        // check from which td we are dragging
        var fromTD = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        // get the inner html content for the td we are dragging the div from 
        var cell = $(ui.draggable).html();
        // insert the complete html content into the target drop cell
        $(this).html(cell);
        // for purposes of result logging / debugging
        var location = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#result').html('Moved '+cell+'<br>From '+fromTable+' / '+fromTD+' (table / td)<br>To cell: '+location+'<br>complete with containing DIV');
        // in case we moved cell content within table2, remove the original content
        if(fromTable == "table2"){
            $(ui.draggable).html('<div></div>');
        }
    }
});

bin.droppable({
    accept: 'td',
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // check if we are dragging from table 2 
        var fromTable = $(ui.draggable).closest("table").attr("id");
        if(fromTable != "table2"){
            $('#result').html('You cannot move content<br>from '+fromTable+' to the trash bin...');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // check from which td we are dragging
            var fromTD = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
            // get the inner html content for the td we are dragging the div from 
            var cell = $(ui.draggable).html();
            // insert the complete html content into the target drop cell
            $(this).html(cell);
            // for purposes of result logging / debugging
            var location = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#result').html('Moved '+cell+'<br>From '+fromTable+' / '+fromTD+' (table / td)<br>To the trash bin');
            // replace the content of the source td after drop
            $(ui.draggable).html('<div></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

});